# Comment loses characters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Please see my comment to this question (starting with "#define ToggleCase..."

[How could these case conversion functions be improved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883993/please-critique-an-optimal-function-for-converting-string-cases-in-c)

The text loses some characters as I point out in the comment.

I've reused the same text in an answer for comparison.

Comment: Are you aware that (a subset of) Markdown is allowed in comments? \* is used for *italic* text, and \*\* for **bold**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple: code should be in a `code block`

`like this`

Comment: okay.just thought it could be symptomatic

Comment: @slash you may also escape the relevant markdown chars in comments by prefixing them with a slash \ like \*so\*